# The workflow is in an invalid state. Please correct it in SharePoint Designer and republish it

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, pnp-powershell

I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow created using SharePoint Designer 2013 during migration with Sharegate I get the error below:-

> The workflow is in an invalid state. Please correct it in SharePoint Designer and republish it. 
>    Details: "The list "ListGUID ID" is required for this workflow and cannot be found at the source."

Fair enough it seems the list has been deleted and some how still being referenced in the source list. I export the workflow in from SharePoint Designer into an `.vwi` extension changed it to a zip file and I analysed the `workflow.xoml` and I can see the orphan list guid is trying to use that it can't find.

I replaced it with the new list GUI and packaged it up back to `.vwi` only to found out I can't import it back via SharePoint Designer 2013 because it says the file is not valid.

Is there a way to import this type of workflow back without having to recreate the whole new workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following article to export and import SharePoint Designer 2013 List Workflow:

https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2013-list-workflow/

If there is the error, make sure the workflow is correct, that is to say when you replaced the list with the new list GUI, make sure the new list has the same fields with the old lists.

Comment: I had field that was being referenced to some other old lists in the workflow. After fixing that and re-ran it with migrated the workflow.